# How to assign a mpz_t type value to a pointer to a structure?

Tags: c, gmp

Okay, for cryptographic purposes I am using the "gmp.h" library in C. Here are the lines of the code (if it is not enough, then kindly inform me how much else I need to provide) and the corresponding errors from Valgrind (as I was getting segmentation fault).

the error from valgrind

```
==5121== Invalid read of size 4
==5121==    at 0x4054E2: __gmpz_set (in /home/debasmita/gf)
==5121==    by 0x403B30: main (ecdsa.c:901)
==5121==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

The minimalized code

```
...
#include <gmp.h>
#include <assert.h>
...
void main(void)
{
...
int flag;
mpz_t inf;
mpz_init(inf);
char inputstr[1024];
...
scanf("%1023s",inputstr);
flag = mpz_set_str(inf,inputstr,10);
assert(flag == 0);
...
mpz_set(zerO->y,inf);
...

}
```

line 901 in my code is

```
mpz_set(zerO->y,inf);
```

zerO is a pointer to a structure

```
typedef struct {
mpz_t x,y,z;
}epnt;
epnt *zerO;
```

Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your pointer `zerO` does not point to a valid address. You never assign any address to it in the code you show. If that is a global variable, it contains `NULL` or if it is local variable it is indetermined.

Comment: ohh yeah! Got it. Thanks.